# QGIS add layer not working

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, layers

I have QGIS 2.8. I open up the database manager, connect to PostGIS, and then execute a query. The resulting query has an id column, a name column, a geom column, and a membership column.

I click on the button "Load as new Layer" and then the button "Load Now!" Nothing happens after that. The layer does not appear in any layer list. I have looked at the documentation and cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you edit your question and add an image showing the query window?

Answer (score 1):

Qgis has got an informative error in the status bar for all the layers being loaded. Try to read what the error says after loading the layer. Another source of error could be that your I'd column is not unique . Test to see if it that is the case

Comment: I can't see any status bar at all. Nothing happens at all. The only message I see is "Table Retrieval Finished."

Answer (score 0):

Modify your sql query to select only the geometry column. I had same problem - I think the layer creation was failing I had 2 columns with same name, after a join. Selecting only the geom column allowed the layer to be created.